# How to use a python module in combination with a command from shell

Tags: python, shell, gnuplot

I would like to use a python module from shell (to be exact: indirect from gnuplot). I do *not* want to write for every call an extra script or implement some I/O logic.

Let's say as a minimal working example, I have a python module `module_foo.py` with

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
def bar():
    print(1,2,3)
```

My question is:

**Why isn't it possible to use a python module combining module loading and command execution like here?:**

```sh
$ python -m module_foo -c 'bar()'
```

When executed, nothing happens. But what does work, is using only a command call like this

```sh
$ python -c 'import module_foo; module_foo.bar()'
1 2 3
```

or this

```sh
$ python -c 'from module_foo import *; bar()'
1 2 3
```

As soon as I load a module before, even a syntactically errorneous command is “accepted” – not executed, I suppose (the bracked of the call to `bar` isn't closed):

```sh
$ python -m module_foo -c 'bar('
$
```

It is, however, possible to use the `-m` module option using a python unit test (from the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/unittest.html)):

```py
python -m unittest test_module1 test_module2
```

The python manpage says for both options:

```
-c command
Specify the command to execute (see next section).  This terminates the option
list (following options are passed as arguments to the command).
-m module-name
Searches sys.path for the named module and runs the corresponding .py file as
a script.
```

So I'd expect to be able to use path options in this `-m ... -c ...`, but not in reverse order `-c ... -m ...`'. Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1):

If you want your Python module to be executable and to call function `bar()`, you should add this to the end of the python file:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":  # this checks that the file is "executed", rather than "imported"

    bar()  # call the function you want to call
```

Then call:

```
python module_foo.py
```

If you want more control, you can pass arguments to the script and access them from `sys.argv`.

For even more flexibility in arguments passed to the script, see [argparse module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html).